Rainbow coloured horizon opposite sunrise
This is my first post, so I apologise in advance for its poor quality.
Yesterday morning I was on an early morning flight over New Zealand's South Island travelling North. At around 7:00 am, the sun had just risen in the east, and I was sitting on the opposite side of the plane. Out my window, I took the photo attached facing west. Sadly, my phone camera could not adequately capture the colours I could see, I was able to see each colour of the rainbow, to my surprise, even a sliver of green was visible. In the photo, most colours are visible, but they were more vibrant to my eyes.
I have a basic understanding of how light works, but could someone explain to me how this works? It looked spectacular, and I want to understand it.
Additional, If this particular phenomenon has a name, I would greatly appreciate learning it.


This probably is the Belt of Venus

It does appear to be, some photos I saw online of it looked quite similar to the photo I took. Thanks for the help @klanomath.
